# How to plot x, y in a graph using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Please help me to plot x, y in graph using **VB.net**. Like shown in the picture. It is an `Lagrange Polynomial`.

[image: Lagrange Polynomial Picture]

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read through [ask], and [edit] your question to include a [mcve] for the part that you are having trouble with.

Comment: You would use the Chart class, which you'll find under the Data section of the Toolbox. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456391(v=vs.110).aspx